# How do I make sure blur event finishes before click event

Tags: jquery, events

I have found questions regarding how to get the blur event to wait for the click event.  However, I want to do the reverse.

Basically, I have code where you enter information into a text area and when that textarea loses focus its contents move to another textarea and then the user clicks 'Update' to send that information (contained in the second textarea) to the server. However, the user is entering text into the first textarea then clicking the 'Update' button and nothing gets sent.

I think I would like to try and delay the click event to wait for the contents of the first textarea to populate the second one before data is sent to the server.  How can I get this to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Have the click event check to see whether the second textarea has contents, and if not, perform the blur event's action before its own.  Or revise whatever you're doing to not need rearranging of the input fields before submitting...

Comment: Not ideal, but you could add a setTimeout to the click handler and it will run when all other event handlers have completed.

Comment: Depending on the scenario, you could just call the blur event of the source text area when the button is clicked.

Comment: This is a common issue with relying on blur finishing before submitting form data. Could you not use a keyup/keypress/input event handler to update the related textarea immediately as the user types?

Comment: Thank you freedom, adding the setTimeout to the click handler worked.